# How best to determine which of these is the washing machine cold water outlet?

Tags: washing-machine

In the pic you can see the two water outlets for my washing machine.  I had marked these out previously but seems markings came off with wallpaper.  I had 2 red handle on one of which broke so the red handle wouldn't be a good indicator.

I am in the UK if that helps.  I think I read somewhere that left is hot and cold is right.  In this case they're above and below so not sure.

Just to add it’s an amica aw5i0lp so only has a cold intake.

Is there a way I can know without making a big mess?  If I have to unleash the water whats the best way to do it without flooding the place.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Supposed to flush the lines into a bucket anyway, but no one actually does that. The hot will have more crud on it... unless the cold had a leak the whole time. If inside one of them it's white with scale, that's the hot. Probably....

Comment: You're asking about "intakes" but the pic you're showing us appears to be of "outlets", then say that your washing machine only has a cold intake... Are your actually trying to identify those 2 *outlets* to work out which one to hook up to your machine's intake?

Comment: The title says "intake," but the question text says "outlets." I'm confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Way 1: Attach hoses to these, direct them into a sink or drain or into your washing machine tub, turn them on and see which one's hot.

Way 2: Turn off the hot water.  There should be a valve near your hot water heater or hot water storage tank that stops water entering or leaving it.  Then *briefly* turn on each of these washer valves using a towel to contain the mess.  The one that works is cold.

Buy a blue handle to replace the broken one, but don't just replace the broken one .... put the blue one on the cold line!  Or buy some blue and red vinyl tape to wrap around the pipes there.

Comment: I was just going to suggest way 1. Flip a coin and hook up the washer. Start a hot cycle and see if hot water starts coming into the washer. If you are lucky you got it right. If not, you swap the hoses once and mark them.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule HOT is on the left COLD is on the right. Most appliances will be marked with an "H" and a "C" where the hoses connect. You can verify this by attaching the hoses to the washing machine. Set the washer to a cold-water cycle. If the water filling the tub is cold you have it attached correctly. If the tub fills with warm water you have the hoses connected incorrectly. Be aware the water may have to run for a minute or two for the heated water to reach the washer.

Comment: I just bought new washer, inside of inlet's are colored, red, blue.

Comment: @bsd, I've also seen an "H" or "C" stamped into the sheet metal on the back of the washers from some manufacturers.